# Why does rails not respond to the ajax post request with javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a button with a click even handler:

```
score_button_click_handler = (e) ->
$.ajax
      url: "/practice_scores/#{practice_score_id}.json",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      processData: false,
      data: "{ \"practice_score\": {\"score_id\": #{score_id}, \"practice_id\": #{practice_id} }}",
      beforeSend: (xhr) ->
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Http-Method-Override", "PUT");
      success: ->
        category_id = $("#category-practices").data("category-id")
        assessment_id = $("#viz").data("assessment-id")
        render_average assessment_id, category_id
```

In `practice_scores_controller.rb`, I have the action:

```
def update
    @practice_score = PracticeScore.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @practice_score.update_attributes(params[:practice_score])
        format.html { redirect_to questionnaire_path, notice: 'Practice score was successfully updated.' }
        format.json {render "update.js.coffee.erb"}
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @practice_score.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In `app/views/practice_scores/` is `update.js.coffee.erb`. It has a simple console log statement in it.

I can't for the life of me get the update view to render. I have also tried the following just to see if I can get it to respond.

```
format.json {render js: "alert('Something')"}
```

I'm not seeing any thing in the console or having an alert pop up. Ultimately, I'd like to respond to the request with coffee/js to update my UI. Does it have to do with the POST request? I have scoured the blogs and I seem to be doing things they way they describe, but I'm just not seeing a response.

Comment: do you want it to respond with `js` or `json`? (because you're asking for the latter, but expecting it to return the former)?

Comment: I'd like it to respond with js. So, I would change the url to `.js`, datatype to js, etc. to reformat the POST request as a JS call?

Comment: I changed the url, dataType, and contentType and now I'm getting a response with `render js: "console.log('test');"`, but a MissingTemplate error is being thrown when I just have `format.js` or `format.js {}`

Comment: Is your template in the right directory? In the error message Rails tells you where he looked for it. Check if your js template is in one of them.

Comment: Yes, it's in `app/views/practice_scores/` and the error says it looks there. Just solved it. Turns out I had to remove the `.erb` extension from the view.

Comment: See https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/issues/36 for more info about the issues with `.erb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url: "/practice_scores/#{practice_score_id}.json",`

From the above, you are making an ajax call to a .json endpoint, which leads me to believe you were wanting json as a response, but you are not. You probably want a regular url like `/practice_scores/#{practice_score_id}`.

**Assuming you have the route defined properly.......**

I would test that `render "update.js.coffee.erb"`is working on its own, removing the entire respond_to do |format| block.

After you determine that it works...

You would *definitely* not be doing `format.json`, but `format.js`

Answer (score 1):

**JSON**

To add to `Sherwyn Goh`'s answer, you need to appreciate what [`JSON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is for - it's a notation system to help you output / use data in your application

If you submit a JSON request to your app, you'd expect a JSON-encoded response of data, *not* a pure JS response. If you want a pure JS response, just send the request as standard javascript

--

**respond_to**

You may benefit from reading up on the [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html) mechanism of Rails, and the different [mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) on the Internet in general.

Specifically, if you want to bring back pure data (in `JSON` notation), you'll want to send a `json` request. IF you want to cause a piece of functionality to occur, you'll want to send a pure `js` request:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
score_button_click_handler = (e) ->
$.ajax
  url: "/practice_scores/#{practice_score_id}"


#app/controllers/practice_scores_controller.rb
Class PracticeScoresController < ApplicationController
   def update
       ...
       respond_to do |format| 
          format.html
          format.js #-> renders /views/practice_scores/update.js.erb
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. My confusion was not recognizing that a url with .json would return json. For some reason, I thought because it was a POST request the json referred to the date being post not what the server would respond with. All is clear now. Thanks!